Quadratic equations over division rings of dimension 2
Let $\ell$ be a division ring, and let $k$ be a sub division ring.
I know that a quadratic equation $x^2 + ax + b = 0$, with $a, b \in k$ can have more than two solutions in $\ell$, but what if the left dimension of $\ell$ over $k$ (that is, the dimension of $\ell$ as a left vector space over $k$) is $2$ ?

How about $\mathbb{Q}[i,j,k]$ with the usual relations, as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}[i]$, and the equation $x^2+x+1=0$.

@DaveBenson: could you elaborate some more ?

Well, there are more than two solutions. There's at least $\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm i\pm j\pm k)$ (independent signs).

Doesn't even $x^2+1=0$ over the quaternions $\ell=\mathbb H$, with the subring $k=\mathbb C$ work? There are solutions $\pm i,\pm j,\pm k$.
